# Waiting for a jquery .each() loop to finish

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm using .each to loop through a collection of images and doing a memory load of each image to find it's true width and height. Then using these figures to populate an array. Problem is I want to wait till the loop has completed to continue my task. Here's my code:

```
 $.each(items, function(){
     $('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).load(function(){
          myArray.push(this.width);
          myArray.push(this.height);
     });
 });
 console.log(myArray.length);
```

The console always logs 0 because I suspect the console.log is being executed before the .each loop has completed. Would that be correct? And how do I get round it? Big thanks.

Comment: The `$.each` is not asynchronous, the `.load` is.

Comment: As the images are being loaded asynchronously, how do you want this to be handled? Each time an image completes loading you could log the array length by pusing the call to just after `push`. Or as Rody suggested you could do a synchronous call instead. What behavior do you need and for what reason? Obviously you are looking to do more than your question states.

Comment: The end game is I need to load a number of images, which can vary in number and size, compare all the widths and heights to find the upper limit of both. I also need to store both the widths and heights, in an array, for use further into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a value that increments onload, and then compare the value to the next loop.

Pseudo code:

```
i=0;
if(i<images){
load image here
image.onload = i++;
}
```

Comment: I would do the comparison within the .each loop?

Comment: you do the increment in the loop, and check value before the loop

Comment: Sorry. Being totally dim today. I understand the concept, but can't seem to fit it into the context of my code. How would that fit into the .each .load loop?

Comment: Finally sorted it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Load executes asynchronously indeed.

You could use the JQuery Ajax method, this way you can set the call to be synchronous, something like (not tested, just out of my head):

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:    'http://url-to-img',
     success: function(result) {
                 myArray.push(this.width);
                 myArray.push(this.height);
              },
     async:   false
});
```

should do the trick. Look at the Jquery ajax reference docs from the JQuery site for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Mind you, you cannot use synchronous cross domain calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but of the other issues I'm facing is that these images are loaded from another domain. And I don't really want to get into the issues of using proxies to load the images. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe the whenSync plugin is something for you then? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm

Answer (score 1):

[`load`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is called asynchronously. Your each loop has finished, but the images aren't finished loading

Comment: K. How would I get round the issue please?

Comment: It gets complicated really quickly. What happens when all the images are loaded? What happens if only some of the images get loaded? What happens if none of the images load? You could add counter that gets closed over so that each `load` callback can increment the counter and check if all the images have been loaded.

Comment: I see what you mean. How can something so simple be so hard. Fun.

Comment: @user1001421, also, some browsers might not trigger the load event even if the images are loaded (because they might be in the cache).